# Asymmetric error bars in Scipy's odrpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am using Scipy's odrpack to fit a linear function to some data that has uncertainties in both the x and y dimensions. Each data point has it's own uncertainty that is asymmetric.

I can fit a function using symmetric uncertainties, but this is not a true representation of my data.

How can I perform the fit with this in mind?

This is my code so far. It receives input data as a command line argument, and the uncertainties i'm using are just random numbers at the moment. (also, two fits are happening, one for positive data points another for the negative. The reasons are unrelated to this question)

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy.odr.odrpack as odrpack

def f(B, x):
    return B[0]*x + B[1]

xdata = sys.argv[1].split(',')
xdata = [float(i) for i in xdata]
xdata = np.array(xdata)

#find indices of +/- data
zero_ind = np.where(xdata >= 0)[0][0]

x_p = xdata[zero_ind:]
x_m = xdata[:zero_ind+1]

ydata = sys.argv[2].split(',')
ydata = [float(i) for i in ydata]
ydata = np.array(ydata)

y_p = ydata[zero_ind:]
y_m = ydata[:zero_ind+1]

sx_m = np.random.random(len(x_m))
sx_p = np.random.random(len(x_p))

sy_m = np.random.random(len(y_m))
sy_p = np.random.random(len(y_p))

linear = odrpack.Model(f)

data_p = odrpack.RealData(x_p, y_p, sx=sx_p, sy=sy_p)
odr_p = odrpack.ODR(data_p, linear, beta0=[1.,2.])
out_p = odr_p.run()

data_m = odrpack.RealData(x_m, y_m, sx=sx_m, sy=sy_m)
odr_m = odrpack.ODR(data_m, linear, beta0=[1.,2.])
out_m = odr_m.run()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us one data set?

Comment: Do you need to see numbers or does the following suffice?

Each data point is the mean x, y value from a measurement and the asymmetric uncertainties come from the maximum and minimum values measured for that data point.

So I get something like;

mean x, max x, min x, mean y, max y, miny

Comment: It's not ideal but there are experimental limitations at play

Comment: Please,post your data somewhere on the internet,I will try to perform statistics.

Comment: Here is some data https://pastebin.com/8YC69pXb

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you solution with random data,I could not bother to import your data

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.odr.odrpack as odrpack
np.random.seed(1)

N = 10
x = np.linspace(0,5,N)*(-1)
y = 2*x - 1 + np.random.random(N)
sx = np.random.random(N)
sy = np.random.random(N)

def f(B, x):
    return B[0]*x + B[1]
linear = odrpack.Model(f)
# mydata = odrpack.Data(x, y, wd=1./np.power(sx,2), we=1./np.power(sy,2))
mydata = odrpack.RealData(x, y, sx=sx, sy=sy)

myodr = odrpack.ODR(mydata, linear, beta0=[1., 2.])
myoutput = myodr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

Than we got

```
Beta: [ 1.92743947 -0.94409236]
Beta Std Error: [ 0.03117086  0.11273067]
Beta Covariance: [[ 0.02047196  0.06690713]
 [ 0.06690713  0.26776027]]
Residual Variance: 0.04746112419196648
Inverse Condition #: 0.10277763521624257
Reason(s) for Halting:
  Sum of squares convergence
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question - how does this take into account asymmetric uncertainties of the data points?

Comment: You can create sx and sy however you wish.For example, in case first point is -4.936(mean)  -4.934(max)  -4.938(min) ,the value would be 0.002.

Comment: That is a rare example of a data point with symmetric uncertainties. Most of them are not like that. For example, the second data point; -4.211(mean) -4.210(max) -4.213(min)

Comment: @jm22b did you ever get a solution for your problem?